# Auto Scrolling Within a View with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, autoscroll, custom-scrolling

Currently working on a project where I want to implement Auto Scrolling in a view. Is this possible with React Native? I have searched the internet and have not come across anything that shows this capability.

Most Stack Overflow questions and YouTube videos deal with scrolling between different views (not within the same view), scrolling to the bottom (with Scroll To), infinite scrolling, or scrolling responsively. But I haven't been able to find anything dealing specifically with auto-scrolling within a given view.

Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something that just came to my mind would be like...

Store current x and y offset values of the scrollview in the component's state, setState every 'x' seconds with the new offset and call scrollTo() method of scrollview. That would change the x and y offset repetitively and make it looks like is auto scrolling.

PS: I know is not a full solution and should be posted in the comments section but I'm not able to comment yet... hope this helps anyway :)